# Sheafification and restriction to open subset

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$
be a presheaf on $X$. We denote by $\mathcal{F}^+$ the
sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$.

Let $U\subset X$ be an open subset.
We denote by $\mathcal{F}|_U$ the presheaf given by
$\mathcal{F}|_U(V)=\mathcal{F}(U\cap V)$.
How I can prove the isomorphism $\mathcal{F}^+|_U \simeq \mathcal{F}|_U^+$
in a clean way? without recalling the definitions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is a sheaf over $U$. So when one writes $\mathcal{F}|_{U}(V)$, $v$ is an open subset of $U$ and $U\cap V=V$ is trivial. Writing $\mathcal{F}|_U(V)=\mathcal{F}(U\cap V)$ is confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Use the universal property of the sheafification and the fact that a sheaf morphism is an isomorphism if and only if it is an isomorphism on all stalks.

Let $\eta: \mathcal{F}|_U \to \mathcal{F}|_U^+$ and  $\theta: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}^+$ be the canonical sheafification maps, which is are isomorphisms on the stalks. Restricting $\theta$ to $U$ we get a map $\theta|_U: \mathcal{F}|_U \to \mathcal{F}^+|_U$.
 Since $\mathcal{F}^+|_U$ is a sheaf, the universal property of $\mathcal{F}|_U^+$ gives a morphism of sheaves $\alpha: \mathcal{F}|_U^+ \to \mathcal{F}^+|_U$ such that $\alpha \circ \eta = \theta|_U$. Since both $\theta|_U$ and $\eta$ are isomorphisms on stalks, so is $\alpha$. Hence, as a morphism between sheaves, $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.